How to create a Excel formula for converting Cell value to Hexadecimal number?
I am trying to create a excel formulae to find the hexa values from each bits. I have a excel sheet like below image

Here I have a 32-bit binary value (example: from A1 to AE1) and another 32-bit binary value (example: from A6 to AE6). My aim is to write formulas for the first hexadecimal value (32-bit binary value) and the next hexadecimal value (next 32-bit binary value). Finally, I need to get a 64-bit value by combining the first and second 32-bit values.
Result 1: Hexadecimal value (32-bit binary value) format: 0xFFFFFFFF
Result 2: Hexadecimal value (next 32-bit binary value) format: 0xFFFFFFFF
Final result: Hexadecimal value of 64-bit binary format: 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
How can I write a simple 3 formulae to find these 3 Hexa values ? Any suggestions or example?

BIN2HEX() maybe? What have you tried?

@cybernetic.nomad - not very helpful BIN2HEX() is limited to 10 bits.

With MSB on the right

=CONCAT("0x", BIN2HEX(MID(CONCAT(INDEX(--A1:AF1,1,32-COLUMN(A1:AF1)+1)), SEQUENCE(, 4, 1, 8), 8), 2))

=CONCAT("0x", BIN2HEX(MID(CONCAT(INDEX(--A6:AF6,1,32-COLUMN(A6:AF6)+1)), SEQUENCE(, 4, 1, 8), 8), 2))

=CONCAT("0x", BIN2HEX(MID(CONCAT(
--INDEX(A1:AF1,1,32-COLUMN(A1:AF1)+1),
--INDEX(A6:AF6,1,32-COLUMN(A6:AF6)+1)),
SEQUENCE(, 8, 1, 8), 8), 2))




With MSB on the left
=CONCAT("0x", BIN2HEX(MID(CONCAT(--A1:AF1), SEQUENCE(, 4, 1, 8), 8), 2))

=CONCAT(
    "0x",
    BIN2HEX(
        MID(CONCAT(--A1:AF1, --A6:AF6), SEQUENCE(, 8, 1, 8), 8),
        2
    )
)



You don't take care of the MSB...LSB sequence of the samples. In the question it is reversed, so your formula results in an incorrect value.

Thank you very much @Blackcat, I suspected that. That's why I showed the bit positions below. Will sleep on it and update tomorrow :)

Thank you for the suggestion.. I don't required signed value as of now.

You're most welcome @user2986042! In my answer, the input has MSB on the left, if it is reversed please let me know. I'll update the answer reversing the input with this INDEX(--A1:AF1,1,32-COLUMN(A1:AF1)+1).

@nkalvi Please do the reversing. you can update the answer

@user2986042, updated the answer, please test and let me know.

@nkalvi I am getting #VALUE! (
Seems like the formulae got some issue..

@user2986042, sorry to hear it. Could you please provide the input causing the error? As shown in the screenshot, it is working without errors.

There already is an answer on how to bin2dec for numbers longer than 10 bits in excel so it should be easy enough to adapt it for your needs.  If you have Excel 365:
=LET(
    string,TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, A2:AF2),
    dec,SUMPRODUCT(--MID(string,LEN(string)+1-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(string))),1),(2^(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(string)))-1))),
    DEC2HEX(dec))

Or using more of Excel 365:
=LET(
    string, TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, A2:AF2),
    len, LEN(string),
    dec, SUMPRODUCT(--MID(string, SEQUENCE(len, 1, len, -1), 1), 2^(SEQUENCE(len, 1, 0))),
    DEC2HEX(dec))

If you don't have Excel 365 you can use a helper cell.
